# ar_track_alvar mistake on id

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I'm experiencing problem on tag recognition using the ar_track_alvar package: "staring" at the same tag, the id of tag recognized is not stable (for example changing from id:32 to id:210 and back to id:32).
Does anyone have experienced the same problem? Furthermore, is there the option to delimit the tag recognizable?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187543/ar_track_alvar-mistake-on-id/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2017-01-06**:
The **size of the tag** and **camera resolution** matter.

I used tag in size of **4cm** and the id recognition is terrible. I have tried **Xtion** and **primesense Carmine** and the resolution is not enough for such small tag. Right now I'm trying to calibrate my Kinect2 to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes I had the same problem.

You can experiment with the max new marker error parameter. Maybe this helps.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0